# Using "some" to describe units of time

Tags: time, collocation, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns, some-any

"*some minutes, some years, some seconds*" are grammatically incorrect.

But "*a few minutes, a few years, a few seconds*" works.

I'm trying to teach a non-native speaker this nuance but "it just sounds weird" does not feel like a satisfactory explanation. I know it has to do with count and mass nouns, because *some time* is correct and *a few time* is not, and time is a mass noun, and few can only be used with countable nouns. Minutes, years, seconds, etc. are all count nouns.

But, some can in some circumstances be used with count nouns and in others with mass nouns. What's the distinction I'm missing?

From your input I have gathered that some + time unit isn't technically wrong when used unselectively, (the "selective" sense of some is explained by Max Williams) but that it's just awkward in some cases. You don't need a some in any unselective construct with a unit of time. *Years ago, for decades, in minutes, months later, over days.*

Why does it sound awkward? Here's my highly heterodox and basically epistemological explanation. My first argument is that some isn't a totally amorphous quantity, that is, it actually does tell you some info about how much stuff (or how many things) it describes. I think we assume some to be countable, not in the sense of "a count noun", but in the sense that we can readily fathom its size. And furthermore I think that some connotes a smallish number, small enough so that it's readily fathomable, generally like 1-100. (This maximum "some-bound" increases for multiples of 5s, 10s, etc.) I'll give an example. Compare *"I have not eaten meat for some years (now)*" to "*scientists believe that the earth was formed some years ago*". The latter just sounds ironic. So, some sounds weird when used unselectively with large quantities because it seems to conflict with their size.
Some also sounds weird with with very small quantities because it appears to provide little information. This is because we assume that the unit of time was chosen efficiently. We don't expect someone to say "2400 minutes" because it's much easier to say "40 hours". We define very small units by their part of a whole, and we assume that at a certain point someone will start using the next order of magnitude unit. If the unit is chosen efficiently then some does not tell you much about quantity, because the coefficient will stay small, and we assume "some"-size by default unless told otherwise, and some-size is small. In these cases, some is vestigial and should be dropped.
But there's a happy medium where unselective "some" works with countable nouns. It's middle-of-the-range units of time where some begins to serve a purpose. It actually does give a bit of info about the actual quantity of the many things/much stuff. For example, "some years ago" is differently nuanced than just "years ago", it sounds somehow smaller. That justifies including the "some" even though it's correct without it.

Comment: I disagree that "*some minutes, some years, some seconds*" are always incorrect - the construction "*Some minutes later*..." is used not infrequently

Comment: For some minutes or for some seconds might not be as idiomatic as for some years, but all of them are not completely wrong. A few minutes and a few seconds are more popular as the time span is quite short. Who told you they are grammatically incorrect?

Comment: I agree with @costrom.  You can also say, "Some years ago, when I was a lot younger, ...".  In this kind of context, *some* probably implies **more than** *a few*: *some* and *few* tend to have difference nuances.

Comment: ***Some*** used as a determiner: 
You use some in front of the plural form of a noun to talk about a number of people or things, without saying who or what they are, or how many of them there are.
*Some children were playing in the yard.
I have some important things to tell them.* http://www.thefreedictionary.com/some

Comment: Do you think these are patternless collocations, or do they have to do with tense? Because "i will be back in some minutes" just sounds wrong to me.

Comment: ***Some vs a few** seconds, minutes, years*: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+few+minutes%2Csome+minutes%2Csome+years%2Ca+few+years%2C+some+seconds%2C+a+few+seconds&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20few%20minutes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csome%20minutes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csome%20years%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20few%20years%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csome%20seconds%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20few%20seconds%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @nebulon I agree that "back in some minutes" sounds wrong - because there you mean "a few".  The terms are not interchangeable: they have different nuances as I mentioned above.  If you say to someone "This may take some time.", you are implying that it may take longer than they expect, i.e. it may not be worth you waiting - come back later.

Comment: @TrevorD That's how I tried to explain it, but the person I was trying teach explicitly said she meant "some" minutes and not "a few" minutes, and not "30" or "15" or other nice factors of 60 either, basically she did not know how many minutes and could not guarantee it would be a few. Apparently this construct "some minutes" is perfectly acceptable in German, her first language.

Comment: Just in case it wasn't clear, I know that some and few are not synonymous. I'm not asking "is it better to use some or a few in this context", I'm asking "Why CANT I use some in this context (if I can use it in others)?"

Comment: Perhaps a better theory is "it's not wrong, but sometimes it sounds weird."

Comment: I like your question @nebulon!  I would suggest, though, that you edit your Pt 1 - Pt 4 comments into your question so that they are not inadvertently lost.

Comment: great idea, will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that it is because "some" implies a **selection**, like saying "some of the minutes": ie, it implies that there is a list of possible minutes, each of which is a different object, and you're referring to some of them.  This works if you are talking about people or cars: there are a finite amount of cars or people, all unique, and you **can** point to your selection and say "Here are some of the people.", or "Here are some people.".

However, units of time don't work like that: individual minutes aren't unique items you can select from all the possible options.  They're more abstract.  So to say "some of the minutes" feels wrong, and "some minutes" is a contraction of this so feels wrong too.

Comment: That explanation makes perfect sense in this context, but I don't understand why constructions like "some minutes later" (which still sounds odd to me) are used.

Comment: I do think you're right, at least for smaller units of time. I'm curious about how that applies to years. "I've had chronic back pain for some years"  works. "I will have chronic back pain in some years from now" is also correct, as is "I have chronic back pain some years". (same applies to passive forms) A few works in all of these too. And I think it works with over, later, and other prepositions.

Comment: The answer sounds plausible but "some" is acceptable in "I'd like some water" and "He went out for some fresh air" where we  are not speaking of different objects.

Comment: some water and some fresh air are mass nouns, not count nouns

Comment: In the case of "I have chronic back pain some years", it does imply "for some of the years". But "I've had chronic back pain for some years" is not selective.

Comment: it's possible that both the "selectivity" theory and the "length of time" theory are correct. Some is ambiguous. It can mean "a vaguely defined amount of X" or "a vaguely defined portion of a group of X" Some years, I have to go to weddings. = vaguely defined portion of years. I went to a wedding some years ago = a vaguely defined amount of years. But it's possible that as time gets shorter our bias shifts to interpret some more rigidly.

Comment: Further complicating the matter, I think "some" is only necessary when you are using it selectively. Years ago, minutes ago, for years, in minutes, blahblahblah. No some needed. Honestly, it may be that that's why we don't use some with units of time as much as we do a few. It's easier to just drop it altogether. "some" is sort of the default, whereas a few modifies it

Comment: Both some and a few are used for small amounts, but "a few" is smaller and has less range, so it's more descriptive. I suppose I'm getting too philosophical though.

Comment: @nebulon yes i think there are lots of examples where it's acceptable.  I was just trying to explain why it feels wrong in other situations.  I think "some" can be used to mean "a small number of", like "a few" (but probably bigger), rather than a selection.

Comment: you're totally right, yes. it's funny, a few can only work with count nouns and fewer with mass nouns...